# Docusign HMAC mismatch

Tags: docusignapi, hmac, docusignconnect

I`m trying to authenticate the DocuSign request in my WebHook using HMAC but the generated value does not match any of the incoming Signatures.I`m using the same key and the same code as the one in the DocuSign documentation.

My code:

```
exports.ComputeHash = function (secret, payload)
{
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
    hmac.write(payload);
    hmac.end();
    return hmac.read().toString('base64');
};

exports.HashIsValid = function (secret, payload, verify)
{
    const hash = module.exports.ComputeHash(secret, payload);
    console.log(hash);
    return verify === hash;
};

const isValid = exports.HashIsValid("MBbMgWXqOldxxxxxxxxxkQQkNey4",
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0\"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus>.....",
    "MdXRWHj2NuBY89kEpeD7llB+RBhTxbpHfaICfjc5GME=")

console.log(isValid);
```

And the hash generated by my payload is "SFK+pPxbCXOTIL9jZH6oi4vC1XBgoy16aoKrVO4IIi8=".

Comment: Is it not better to test with the payload extracted from the request. What workflow do you plan to use?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and works fine. Make sure to escape all " with back slash. My test failed couple of times before I realized I missed one un-escaped **"**. I am not sure if ** in your verify is part of SO but make sure you remove them when testing

Comment: When the webhook endpoint is hit, then the hash generated from the request payload is not matching the signature all the time.

Comment: I would check for the failed ones if sender's user name contains special characters.